# Creating and using keystore https android

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-keystore

I need to implement https connection to my application. First, I did class, which trusts all certificates, but have read that it's unefficient. Then I decided to use kystore to save keys from the serer. I try to create it in that way in the command promtp:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myproject -keystore C:/myproject.keystore 
-storepass myproject -storetype BKS -provider     
org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

But when I want to use like this:

```
protected static org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory createAdditionalCertsSSLSocketFactory() {
        try {


            final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

            // the bks file we generated above
            final InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource( R.raw.myproject);  
            try {
                // don't forget to put the password used above in strings.xml/mystore_password
                ks.load(in, context.getString( R.string.mystore_password ).toCharArray());
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }

            return new AdditionalKeyStoreSSLSocketFactory(ks);

        } catch( Exception e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

, I can't reach my keystore from the res/raw derictory, nevertheless I put it in the res/raw derictory. And also my R file was deleted ...I tried to implement it with the Portecle interface but I faced the same problem - keystore can't be reached from the res/raw derictory and when I tried to build/clean the project R file was deleted. When I removed the keystore file, R file was recovered.
Tell me please, how can I create the keystore in proper way and use it for my connections.